# Escaping Special Characters in Import for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, special-characters, backticks

In my where clause I am trying to escape a special character "#" by following [the manual's](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/cypher-expressions.html) recommendation regarding backticks when creating a node:

```
WHERE line.`The #` IS NOT NULL AND line.`Person's First/Last Name` IS NOT NULL
```

However, when I do this, I get message:

> No data returned, and nothing was changed.

Am I escaping the header values ("The #" and "Person's First/Last Name") properly?

Comment: I would not recommend ever to use such property names, even if it is possible !!

Comment: @MichaelHunger why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example code works for me, doesn't look like your problem is the escape characters.

```
CREATE (n:TestNode { `The #`:"123", `Person's First/Last Name`:"john johnson" });

MATCH (line)
WHERE line.`The #` IS NOT NULL AND line.`Person's First/Last Name` IS NOT NULL
RETURN line.`The #`, line.`Person's First/Last Name`;

line.`The #`    line.`Person's First/Last Name`
123 john johnson
Returned 1 row in 128 ms
```

Comment: Turns out I mis-referenced a header in the import (foolishly!).